# Python: Average number of drawings (Randomly generated numbers)

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and I hope for some help or guides by asking here.

Here's the problem:
Write a program that estimates the average number of drawings it takes before the user’s numbers are picked in a lottery that consists of correctly picking six different numbers that are between 1 and 10. To do this, run a loop 1000 times that randomly generates a set of user numbers and simulates drawings until the user’s numbers are drawn. Find the average number of drawings needed over the 1000 times the loop runs.

I tried to create something (below), but I just can't think of how to get those average number. Also it seems the loop is not good. Any help or solution? thank you in advance.

```
from random import randint
from random import choice            #???

userlist = []
for y in range(6):
        user = input("Enter your entry no.{} lotto number: ".format(y+1))
        userlist.append(user)

x = 0
randomlotterylist = []
while not x>1000:
        lottery = []
        for i in range (6):
                lot.append(randint(1,10))
        randomlotterylist.append(lottery)
        x = x + 1

#Next.. ????
```

Comment: `but I just can't think of how to get those average number` Take the sum of the list and divide by the length?

Comment: Um.. what length? the number of indexes or the numbers inside? is the answer will be in [n,n,n,n,n,n] format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to know your theoretical average number of drawings, that's (1/10)^6 assuming no repetition allowed.  Therefore on average every 1,000,000 tries you'd hit the correct number.  That is only if the order matters but I assume in your case the order does not matter, so def your average is less than that...

```
from random import randint

def number_of_tries_before_hitting_jackpot(user_number):
    n_tries = 0
    while True:
        random_number = set([randint(1,10) for i in range(1,7)])
        if user_number == random_number:
              return n_tries
        else:
              n_tries+=1

def ask_user_his_number():
   userlist = []
   for y in range(6):
        user = input("Enter your entry no.{} lotto number: ".format(y+1))
        userlist.append(user)
   return set(userlist)

n_tries_list = []
for x in range(1,1001):
       user_number =  ask_user_his_number()
       print user_number
       tmp = number_of_tries_before_hitting_jackpot(user_number)
       print tmp
       n_tries_list.append(tmp)
avg_number_drawings = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, n_tries_list) / len(n_tries_list)
print avg_number_drawings
```

This code is not what I'd do in the sense that the user needs to input its 6 numbers 1,000 times (v annoying for the user).  You could change the ask_user_his_number function to a function that just randomly selects a set of 6 numbers.

Answer (score -2):

by using random module, for loop, list in short without defining fuction.

```
from random import *  

user_num=[]
count=0
for i in range(6):
     random_num=randint(1,10)
     user_num+=[random_num]
     user_num.sort()

for j in range(1000):
     picked=[]
     for k in range(6):
          pick_num=randint(1,10)
          picked+=[pick_num]
          picked.sort()
     if picked==user_num:
          count+=1
print("the avg darwing is: ",count, count/1000)
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!